# How to evaluate at least one of the conditions is true

Tags: sql

```
    /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
    SELECT
          [ProductID]
          ,[Name]
          ,[ProductNumber]
          ,[MakeFlag]
          ,[FinishedGoodsFlag]
          ,[Color]
          ,[SafetyStockLevel]
          ,[ReorderPoint]
          ,[StandardCost]
          ,[ListPrice]
          ,[Size]
          ,[SizeUnitMeasureCode]
          ,[WeightUnitMeasureCode]
          ,[Weight]
          ,[DaysToManufacture]
          ,[ProductLine]
          ,[Class]
          ,[Style]
          ,[ProductSubcategoryID]
          ,[ProductModelID]
          ,[SellStartDate]
          ,[SellEndDate]
          ,[DiscontinuedDate]
          ,[rowguid]
          ,[ModifiedDate]
      FROM [AdventureWorks2012].[Production].[Product]
```

I want to be able to select all the records where at least either color, size or style isn't null. So for each record one of the three columns should have a value. 
How would I archive this? I'm quite confused. I simply don't get how I can get it so that at least one of the columns have a value.  Am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Do you know what a `where` clause is?

Comment: Someone else posted this, and I was about to post the same thing until I saw theirs: `WHERE color IS NOT NULL OR style IS NOT NULL  OR size IS NOT NULL` You said it was wrong. The answer has been deleted. How  is it wrong? For the code to execute and select the correct records only one 'OR' has to evaluate to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT
WHERE COLOR IS NOT NULL
OR SIZE IS NOT NULL
OR STYLE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: that isn't correct because that would yield the possibility of all three being null

Comment: Things where All 3 columns are null are NOT found by my query...only things in which 1 of the columns has content will be returned

Comment: @Ageis This is correct. If all three are `null` that whole statement would be `false` and no records would be selected where all three are null. Or have I lost it?

Comment: You are looking for "if any of these 3 columns has a value, give me it"

This query basically goes
"Is color null? (if it is not- its good return it) (if it is null...)

Is size null? (if it is not- its good return it) (if it is null...)

Is style null? (if it is not - its good return it) (if it is null...)

Well, then all 3 columns are null...exclude it

Comment: Sorry!!School boy error the data-set didn't have any records where colour is null and either one of the others are not null. which led me to believe the query I wrote was wrong since I knew for a fact there were records where the colour wasn't set. I did honestly write the query you've given me. I should ohave suspected the dataset sorry

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
 select (columns you want here)
 from Table
 where (columns that you are matching) is not null
```

I would suggest reading basic tutorials for sql so you can have a better understanding of how SQL works.

Comment: Don't know. Maybe because this doesn't really help. What should be entered at the placeholders? If OP doesn't know the `where` clause you have to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it this way....

```
select  *

from    production.product as prod 

where   coalesce(prod.color, prod.size, prod.style) is not null
```